# Equation by Graph

Tags: analytic-geometry

Given a random Graph,is there any known way to find an equation for it ? If I create a random graph is there a way that i can find an equation that totally describes my random graph?

Comment: If the function is continuous, you may use the Lagrange Interpolating Polynomial.

Comment: What do you mean by "an equation" ? For example, let the graph consist of $n$ random points in the plane.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I see your point; I take it the OP means a polynomial relation in one variable in the plane.

Comment: @DietrichBurde For $n$ points $(x_i, y_i)_{i=1..n}\in \Bbb R^2$ the equation for $(x,y)$ might be $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n\left((x-x_i)^2+(y-y_i)^2\right)=0$. You may also replace $\prod$ with $\sum$..

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose that the "random" graph you drew represents some function $y = f(x)$. In other words, above each point of the $x$-axis, there is at most one point on your graph.

Then there are a few ways to get an equation that gives a very good approximation of $f$, at least. If the function $f$ is continuous (i.e. you drew it without lifting your pen from the paper), then you can find a polynomial function that's everywhere very close to $f$. By "very close" I mean as close as you want, actually. This is is guaranteed by something called the [Weierstrass Approximation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).

If you actually want to compute the equation of an approximating polynomial (rather than just being assured that it exists), then I recommend a piece of software called chebfun. If you look on [the chebfun web site here](http://www.chebfun.org/examples/approx/index.html), you'll see some of the wiggly random-looking graphs for which it can find equations.